# How to execute a function until Firestore complete downloading data by Swift?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have searched a lot of information on Google but still no any solution could resolve my problem...

I want to show a list on UI which needs the data on Firestore, but everytime the list will be empty because it didn't wait for the Firestore downloading. How can I solve it?

Here is my code:

```
private var imgList: [String] = []
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        downloadfromFilestore()
        bindingView()
}

func downloadfromFirestore(){
    //firestore official code
    for i firestoreDataResult in{
        imgList.append(i.imgURL)
    }
}

func bindingVIew(){
    customElement.setURLs(imgList)
}
```

I have already tried so many solutions such as DispatchQueue, DispatchGroup, async.....
I am very new in Swift so please help me..

Comment: It all depends on this _firestore official code_ you didn't post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your downloadFromFilestore should be looking something like that (according to the docs):

```
func downloadFromFiresfore() {
  let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")
  docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        // reload UI here. This part will be executed only when download is completed. 
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
  }
}
```

Pay attention to where the reload UI code should be put. (I guess you’ve put it outside of the completion block)

In general it is not very recommended to perform database access from inside a view controller but to create a service which will manage all the calls for you, and will be accessible from any VC. 
Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Official firestore swift code for your `func downloadFromFirestore()`

```
let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("collectionName").document("documentID")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        //document downloaded
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

More official swift fitestore code https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?refresh=1